# hl.fragsize not respected in my query

Tags: solr, fragment, highlighting

I am using solr 3.5, and in my search query I set `hl.fragsize = 100`, but my fragment does not contain exactly 100 chars, in fact, average fragment size is 120.

Can anybody have idea about this issue?

Comment: Are you merging contiguous fragments (mergeContinuous)?

Comment: @Ansari, no I am not merging contiguous fragments.

Comment: Are you maybe using fast vector highlighter?

Comment: @javanna , nope i am not using  fast vector highligher as well :(

Answer (score 1):

Check out the hl.regex.slop parameter.

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters#hl.regex.slop

Answer (score -1):

maybe just do some post-processing like

```
if (highlight.length() > HIGHLIGHT_MAX_LENGTH) {
    int idx = highlight.toString().indexOf(" ", HIGHLIGHT_MAX_LENGTH);
    String excerpt = StringUtils.left(highlight.toString(), idx);
    if (!excerpt.endsWith(".")) {
            return excerpt + HIGHLIGHT_MORE;
    }
    return excerpt;
}
```

The highlight var is a StringBuilder. Hope this helps.